# Реализовать запись звука в *.wav файл

Tags: delphi, аудио

Здравствуйте! Как можно реализовать запись звука в *.wav файл, используя компонент Media Player?

Comment: Советую Вим использовать компонент Bass.dll.

Answer (score 4):

Читайте тут: [ссылка первая](http://www.programmersclub.ru/запись-звука-с-помощью-mediaplayer/), [ссылка вторая](http://www.delphimaster.net/view/8-43690/all), [ссылка третья](http://www.kansoftware.ru/?tid=3631)

Думаю этого достаточно, чтобы сделать, то что вы описали...

Comment: @IntegralAL, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. По возможности добавляйте код правильного решения в ваш ответ, так как статьи на сторонних стайтах могут быть удалены.

Comment: @Expert, хорошо буду стараться приводить код в самом ответе или свои наработки выкладывать.